# How do I ensure privilege to update record?

Tags: php, security

I received some pen tests results.
The results say that anybody can update any record by just changing a certain id.

[image: pen test result]

How could I ensure that the user can only update his own record in this function?

```
public function actionUpdateProfile()
{
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $response = array("status" => "1", "message" => "Profile update successful.");
    $data = json_decode($postdata);
    $model = HosDoctors::model()->findByPk($data->doctor_id);

    foreach ($data->fields1 as $field) {

        $_POST[$field->name] = $field->value;
    }

    $enc = NEW bCrypt();

    $model->attributes = $_POST;

    if ($model->save()) {
        $response = array("status" => "1", "message" => "Profil erfolgreich aktualisiert");
    } else {
        pr($model->getErrors());
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    die;
}
```

Would it be sufficient to simply check for

```
if (cookie == $data->doctor_id)
{
    //ok
}
else
{
    //we are not logged as the user id that we want to update, so deny updating
    die;
}
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If it were me, I'd use PostgreSQL to protect medical data at the database layer, by deploying an RBAC scheme, using the authorization of PostgreSQL which is already tested and production ready. You should also take note of the [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html), and tie the user ID to the session, before allowing any changes.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the person has "logged in" in some way so that you know "who they are". While security is complex and is definitely not a one-answer topic; at its simplest level, once you have identified the user, use PHP session handling to persist their identity across one or many http/s requests, then internally access any related information using the session cookie id for the duration of the session.

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential issues in this function (unless you posted a heavily edited version). I'll note them as comments.

```
public function actionUpdateProfile()
{
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $response = array("status" => "1", "message" => "Profile update successful.");
    // Never initialize responses until you really *must*. Chances that a partially prepared response might be output are slight, but why run risks?
    // And actually you **do** reinitialize $response later on!
    $data = json_decode($postdata);
    // You are not verifying that $data *exists* (i.e. the JSON data was, indeed, JSON). You should check that $data is not NULL and that it does have **all** the required fields and that they are valid.
    // This is the point where you validate $data->doctor_id, by the way. Or you check that patient_data matches with whatever you have in your $_SESSION or Session app object.

    $model = HosDoctors::model()->findByPk($data->doctor_id);

    // This is a bad practice. Yes, you have some code that relies on 
    // _POST. If necessary, wrap it in another code that will set up
    // _POST from an input and then delete it. Otherwise you're leaking
    // data into a superglobal. You don't want to do that.
    foreach ($data->fields1 as $field) {
        $_POST[$field->name] = $field->value;
    }

    // Why are you initialising $enc?
    $enc = NEW bCrypt();

    // This is not very good. $_POST could contain *other* information
    // unless it's been sanitized outside the function.
    // I would prepare a setter function, $model->setArray($data), that
    // would verify the validity of the attributes before setting them.
    $model->attributes = $_POST;

    if ($model->save()) {
        $response = array("status" => "1", "message" => "Profil erfolgreich aktualisiert");
    } else {
        pr($model->getErrors());
    }
    // This works in 90% of the browsers and scenarios. But I'd
    // set up a function that would also send the appropriate
    // Content-Type headers to satisfy the remaining 10%.
    echo json_encode($response);
    die;
    // e.g. Utilities::jsonResponse($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be sufficient to simply check for
>
> if (cookie == $data->doctor_id) {
> //ok } else {
> //we are not logged as the user id that we want to update, so deny updating
> die; }

try checking by **user token** instead of **user-id** because user-id can be found within some page url or body but the token is hard to get unless using network sniffing technics.

> you can generate user token by any token generation method and then store it as a column in the user table in your database.

token generation method e.g

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

# or in php7
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be sufficient to simply check for
>
> ```
> if (cookie == $data->doctor_id)
> {
>     //ok
> }
> else
> {
>     //we are not logged as the user id that we want to update, so deny updating
>     die;
> }
> ```

No, in principle this is actually the same as you already have: the ID is still part of the request and can be changed like you got it reported.

Instead ensure the request is first of all authorized, then fetch the related data from the identity and access management system.

If you do not have anything to manage identity and access, choose a system and integrate it first.

From the code you've posted so far it is not visible (to me) whether or not such a system exists. Therefore I can not specifically answer on that detail.

Authentication/Authorization of requests is part of the HTTP protocol and is supported at a basic level in PHP out of the box. See:

- [HTTP authentication with PHP <sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)

If you want to roll your own completely you can consider HTTP state management with PHP sessions, but as you ask the question the way you ask it (with all due respect), my suggestion is to take something that already exists, is proven and easy for you to understand and integrate (less complexity = better software and less flaws/holes).

Take the event of the pen test and its result to address the design issues first and find a high level solution not that you need to patch multiple endpoints individually only to address the same basic flaw.

Let the system work for you.

After the pen-test I would also suggest the code is reviewed with dedication towards the found issues and the code writers are trained based on the results of both.

---

> Would it be sufficient to simply check for ...

Yes, given the cookie is from a safe source and all its properties are secure. E.g. only the identity and access management system can add it to the HTTP request that hits the PHP SAPI.

I would rate this event very unlikely as you needed to ask the question.

And it would be very unorthodox if it would contain a concrete id. There should always be a HTTP state management and it should be rolling to protect against replay attacks with credentials or at least limit the time-frame in which they are valid.

But purely technically, with the right design and implementation I can imagine there can be systems that work this way (HTTP request with cookie as secure token).

Take care.